# Create histogram based from multiple selected checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, google-visualization

i have a list of checkboxes, right now i am able to retrieve data at database from multiple selected checkbox, and display them in a table.. below this is the code..

But my problem is how to display **similar output** data just like in **comparetable.php** to a **histogram**..i tried to used google chart but it just display data of a histogram exactly from the database, not getting from **multiple selected checkboxes**. Thank you very much for your time...

history.php

```
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" action="comparetable.php">
<table>

         <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
         </tr>

     <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM compareresult where idmember='$idmembersession'";
    $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                        $title = $data['subject'];
          ?>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedcheck[]" 
       value="<?php  echo $title ?>"/></td>

        <?php
        echo "<td>$title</td>"
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
 </table> 

  <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "submit1"  VALUE = "COMPARE SELECTED"></form>
```

comparetable.php

```
<body>SUSTAINABILITY OF PERCENTAGE </br></br></br>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>TITLE</th>
<th>PERCENTAGE RESULT</th>
</tr>

<?php 

 if(isset ($_POST["submit1"]))
{
$checkbox = isset($_POST['selectedcheck']) ? $_POST['selectedcheck'] :  array();
foreach($checkbox as $title)
    {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM compareresult where subject='".$title."'";
    $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
        {

                $result = $data['result'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result."</td>";    
                echo "</tr>";   
        }
    }
}

?>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: If i understand correct, you want, when you check the checkboxes, inmideatly change your histogram? Cause without updating the page, you need to make an AJAX call. If you want it to be put in your database, you have to add in your while statement an insert query to insert your data in your database.

Comment: @Dorvalla yes..the chart will be generate based on if user check two or more checkbox in checkboxlist, then retrieves data that are related to the checked checkbox, then display the data in histogram.. :( ..no need to put it database..